# Spinner onItemSelected() not being called

Tags: android, kotlin

I've implemented an `ArrayAdapter` to populate my `Spinner` view. The `Spinner` is working fine, however android is not detecting when I click an item in the spinner.

I've abided by all the requirements in the [spinner example in the Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner)
 including implementing `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` to my Activity and overriding it's two methods `OnItemSelectedListener` and `onNothingSelected`, however, none of my `Log` statements in those methods print so they are not being called.

I've also set the listener to my spinner via `choose_user.onItemSelectedListener = this@PlayerDetails`.

**Here's my activity:**

```
class PlayerDetails : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener, TextWatcher, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    val TAG: String = "PlayerDetails"
    val FirebaseTAG: String = "FirebaseDebug"

    var numOfPlayers: Int = 1
    var currentPlayer: Int = 1

    var name: String = ""
    var age: Int = 0
    var genderId: Int = 0
    var genderResult: String = ""

    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    var users: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityPlayerDetailsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val sharedPref = this@PlayerDetails.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val applicationID: String? = sharedPref.getString("applicationID", null)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_player_details)

        if (applicationID != null) {

            db.collection("phones").document(applicationID)
                .collection("users")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { result ->

                    for (document in result){
                        val name = document.get("name").toString()
                        users.add(name)
                    }
                }

            Log.d(FirebaseTAG, users.toString())
            val spinnerAdaptor = ArrayAdapter<String>(this@PlayerDetails, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, users)
            spinnerAdaptor.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            choose_user?.adapter = spinnerAdaptor
            choose_user.onItemSelectedListener = this@PlayerDetails
        }

        val intent = getIntent()
        numOfPlayers = intent.getIntExtra("number_of_players", 1)
        next_details.setOnClickListener(this)
        player_name.addTextChangedListener(this)
        player_age.addTextChangedListener(this)
        gender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(object: RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {
            override fun onCheckedChanged(radiogroup: RadioGroup, checked: Int) {
                if (fieldsArePopulated()) next_details.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        })

    }

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, name: View?, position: Int, rowId: Long) {
        val chosenName: String = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
        Log.d("ChosenName", chosenName)
        Log.d("adapterclicked", "adapterclicked")

    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        Log.d("Nothing", "NOTHINGCALLED")
    }

...
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Also, when I select an item in the Spinner the view next to my spinner moves, so it's obviously being detected but `onItemSelected()` is still not being called.

Comment: I reproduced your code and it works fine. I confirm that `onItemSelected()` is called. Did you put a breakpoint inside it?

Comment: What do you mean by breakpoint?

Comment: By clicking at the left of a line in AS editor (at the right od the line number), a red dot will appear. This way you set a **breakpoint**. Then run the app in **debug mode**. The app will stop when the code reaches that line. Read more here: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Comment: Thanks. I haven't set any breakpoints, so very confused why onItemSelected() isn't being called.

Comment: So set a breakpoint inside onItemSelected() and press Shift+F9 to run in debug mode. If when you make a selection in the spinner the code does not stop then you are sure that onItemSelected() is not called.

Comment: I set an initial value to the users MutableList `var users: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("Choose User")` and now onItemSelected() is successfully being called. Thanks for the debug tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set an initial value to the `users` MutableList:

```
var users: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("Choose User")
```

and now `onItemSelected()` is successfully being called.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure onItemSelected returns an int of the item's position in array. So you have to save that as an int instead of string, and then add another variable that us a string and array[intSaved]

**Edit**

```
var chosenName = choose_user.onItemSelected("name")
```

Comment: Thanks I'll do that - but first need to find out why `onItemSelected()` isn't firing at all. Edit: Actually the docs say `getPositionAtPosition(int)` will return the data of the `int` position of the array so my code looks fine in that sense: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView#getItemAtPosition(int)

Answer (score 0):

try this

before :

```
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, name: View?, position: Int, rowId: Long) {
    val chosenName: String = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
    Log.d("ChosenName", chosenName)
    Log.d("adapterclicked", "adapterclicked")

}
```

after :

```
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, name: View?, position: Int, rowId: Long) {
    val chosenNameTextView = parent!!.getChildAt(0) as TextView
    Log.e("MainActivity","choose Spin : ${chosenNameTextView.text.toString()}")
}
```

Comment: Just tried this - `onItemSelected()` still isn't calling.

Comment: what do you mean about "onItemSelected isn't calling ?"

Comment: The Log statement inside it wasn't showing so I assumed it want being called. However I posted a solution.

Comment: so, the problem is 'method onItemSelected and method onNothingSeleceted' can't call from your activity ?

if yes, use this, code.

choose_user.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{}

if 'object' show 'red underline', click Alt+Enter to call onItemSelected and onNothingSelected method.